# ¿Cómo agrupar múltiples columnas dentro de una lista de objetos de linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

En mi proyecto web asp.net hago uso de un procedimiento almacenado que me devuelve resultados con la siguiente estructura.

```
_idPedido   _idCliente  _cliNombre  _idDireccion    _ruta       _desDireccion           Id_producto id_servicio tipo_unidad
    655         10770       LUIS        10726           107         AMADOR  CARDENAS...     3           1           1
    655         10770       LUIS        10726           107         AMADOR  CARDENAS...     4           3           1
```

Las últimas 3 columnas (Id_producto, id_servicio, tipo_unidad) provienen de una tabla hijo (Pedido > Pedido detalle) que consulto en el stored procedure mediante un join.
Cuando el stored procedure me responde, utilizo esas tres columnas para generar algunas condiciones y valores extra, mi duda se da en el momento que quiero agrupar esos resultados antes de pasarlos al front end, porque necesito hacerlo con la siguiente estructura.

```
_idPedido   _idCliente  _cliNombre  _idDireccion    _ruta       _desDireccion           _detalle
655         10770       LUIS        10726           107         AMADOR  CARDENAS...     [
                                                                                            {Id_producto: 3, id_servicio: 1, tipo_unidad: 1}
                                                                                            {Id_producto: 4, id_servicio: 3, tipo_unidad: 1}
                                                                                        ]
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto utilizando linq?

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Estaría excelente que agregues las clases que utilizas en este procedimiento y el código que intentaste realizar para hacer esta operación así nos orientamos y es más fácil darte una mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pregunta tiene solera pero bueno, contesto.

Desde luego usando GroupBy de LinQ, que no es que sea el más fácil de entender.

El parámetro que se le pasa es la expresión que va a formar la clave de la agrupación, esto significa que puede tener una o múltiples columnas de agrupación, en tu caso simplifico los parámetros:

```
var agrupacion = pedidos.GroupBy(p => new { p.IdPedido, p.IdCliente });
```

Lo que te devuelve es un listado con una clave según hayas formado la agrupación y el listado de objetos agrupados, por tanto debes atenderlo según su estructura:

```
var consulta = agrupacion.Select(x => new PedidoAGrupado
{
    IdPedido = x.Key.IdPedido,
    IdCliente = x.Key.IdCliente,
    Productos = x.ToList().Select(y => new Producto
    {
        IdProducto = y.IdProducto,
        TipoUnidad = y.TipoUnidad
    }).ToList()
});

var listado = consulta.ToList();
```

Para terminar pasándolo a un listado.

Te dejo completo el código de ejemplo, espero que te sea útil.

```
public class Pedido
{
    public int IdPedido { get; set; }
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public int IdProducto { get; set; }
    public int TipoUnidad { get; set; }
}

public class PedidoAGrupado
{
    public int IdPedido { get; set; }
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public List<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
}

public class Producto
{
    public int IdProducto { get; set; }
    public int TipoUnidad { get; set; }
}

public class LinQAgrupados
{
    public void Lanzar()
    {
        List<Pedido> pedidos = new List<Pedido>
        {
            new Pedido{ IdPedido = 655, IdCliente = 10770, IdProducto = 3, TipoUnidad = 1},
            new Pedido{ IdPedido = 655, IdCliente = 10770, IdProducto = 4, TipoUnidad = 1}
        };

        var listaAgrupada = pedidos.GroupBy(p => new { p.IdPedido, p.IdCliente })
            .Select(x => new PedidoAGrupado
            {
                IdPedido = x.Key.IdPedido,
                IdCliente = x.Key.IdCliente,
                Productos = x.ToList().Select(y => new Producto
                {
                    IdProducto = y.IdProducto,
                    TipoUnidad = y.TipoUnidad
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Claro!, esa pregunta la publiqué hace ya un buen tiempo, y precisamente así lo resolví. Gracias por contestar, y esperamos que le sirva a algún lector en el futuro.